# SQL Get Parent Record Chain

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have a table like so:

```
|ItemID|ItemName|ParentID|
|... etc more records ...|
|1234  |Itemlol |432     |
|... etc more records ...|
|1543  |Kthxhi  |1234    |
|... etc more records ...|
|1938  |FunTimes|1543    |
|... etc more records ...|
|3765  |Apples  |1938    |
|... etc more records ...|
|8634  |Oranges |3765    |
|... etc more records ...|
```

Can I make a query where I pass in 3765 and get back:

```
|1234  |Itemlol |432     |
|1543  |Kthxhi  |1234    |
|1938  |FunTimes|1543    |
```

Or, even better... also pass in a "Number of Parents" and get back that many records, since there may be 30 or more parents, but I typically only want 8.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: That's a task for recursion, most DBMSes (besides MySQL) support it.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a hierarchyid evangelist. HierarchyID is a not-often-used datatype that was introduced in SQL 2008 that encodes, well, a hierarchy. The data you have is a classic way to encode a hierarchy. That is, each record has a (potentially null) parent id that points to another record in the table. Let's walk through augmenting your data. First, a bog standard recursive common table expression (CTE):

```
create table #items (
    ItemID int not null,
        constraint PK_Items primary key clustered (ItemID),
    Name nvarchar(100) not null,
    ParentItemID int null,
        constraint [FK_Items_Parent] foreign key
            (ParentItemID) references #items (ItemID)
);

insert into #items (ItemID, Name, ParentItemID)
values
    (1234  ,'Itemlol ', null     ),
    (1543  ,'Kthxhi  ', 1234    ),
    (1938  ,'FunTimes', 1543    ),
    (3765  ,'Apples  ', 1938    ),
    (8634  ,'Oranges ', 3765    );

alter table #items add h hierarchyid null;

with cte as (
    select ItemID, Name, ParentItemID, cast(concat('/', ItemID, '/') as varchar(1000)) as h
    from #items
    where ParentItemID is null

    union all

    select child.ItemID, child.Name, child.ParentItemID, cast(concat(parent.h, child.ItemID, '/') as varchar(1000)) as h
    from #items as child
    join cte as parent
        on child.ParentItemID = parent.ItemID
)
update i
    set h = cte.h
from #items as i
join cte
    on i.ItemID = cte.ItemID;
```

Note, I changed your data ever so slightly so that there's a clear anchor for the recursion. What we're doing here is calculating the value that the hierarchyid column should have for every row. Next, to answer your actual question:

```
declare @h hierarchyid, @maxLevels tinyint = 2;
set @h = (select h from #items where ItemID = 3765);

select *
from #items as i
where @h.IsDescendantOf(i.h) = 1
    and i.h.GetLevel() >= @h.GetLevel() - @maxLevels
    and i.h <> @h;
```

Note here that I limited it to two levels up in the hierarchy being returned since your data is too shallow to show eight actually limiting the return set. But all you need to do is change the value of `@maxLevels` to 8 when you run it and you should be good to go.

Edit: Since you expressed interest in a classic CTE approach, here's one way to do it. Essentially, you're traversing the hierarchy from the child to the parent instead of parent to child. Compare the two solutions performance-wise on your actual data, though!

```
declare @maxLevel tinyint = 2, @ItemID int = 3765;
with cte as (

    select *, 0 as [level]
    from #items
    where ItemID = @ItemID

    union all

    select parent.*, child.level + 1 as [level]
    from #items as parent
    inner join cte as child
        on child.ParentItemID = parent.ItemID
)
select *
from cte
where [level] <= @maxLevel
    and ItemID <> @ItemID;
```

Comment: I was just about to answer with an out-of-the-book recursive CTE, but your answer is far more interesting. Hierarchyid is quite a hidden gem. Completely SQL server specific I guess, but worth knowing.

Comment: Have you had real world experience with it, such as maintainability and performance?

Comment: I have used HierarchyID before to solve a business problem. It's a win just for the fact that you all of the ancestors are stored in-row. Since you can index HierarchyID, that helps with performance. Maintainability takes some consideration, but isn't terrible. I'll write up a pure cte solution when I'm back at my PC.

Comment: That's awesome.  I wonder if I can use it in my C# and pass it in a SqlConnection.  If not, I can make a Sproc, but it would be cool to see if it works in C#.

Comment: The adding of the HierarchyID column and the population of it are one-time operations (best done through SSMS to be honest). After that, I don't see any barriers to entry from using this wherever. Moreover, HierarchyID is a CLR type that has full support in C# if that's something you're looking to explore.

Comment: In your CTE example you implement the recursion termination condition outside of the CTE itself. I agree that this is logically equivalent to implementing it inside the CTE, but I wouldn't be confident that the optimiser will always realise that it can stop recursing, especially if the condition is not trivial. It would have to determine if the logic outside the CTE is actually terminating recursion or instead just filtering the result of recursion.

Comment: I don't think that recursion in SQL works like recursion in "traditional" programming languages. In SQL, the base case is evaluated *first* and then subsequent rows are added to it. Whereas traditional recursion is you evaluate the top case and have an unresolved reference to a lower case and then need to be told where to stop. In this particular case, we could add a primary key to the #items table so that SQL Server will know that there will be at most 1 row that has a given ItemID.

Comment: @BenThul I made a fiddle on [rextester](http://rextester.com/discussion/UZB93741/Recursive-CTE-termination) to show the difference between terminating recursion inside and outside the CTE.  I'd be interested in your comment.